# Is there a "small cap" version of greek symbols out there?

Tags: symbols, greek, small-caps

I need to use two versions of the Omega greek letter in the same equation, but I don't want to use uppercase and lowercase (as the latter looks like a w). Is there a way to differentiate between the two uppercase Omega characters (perhaps with an equivalent to small caps for latin characters)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a text command in package `tipa` called `\textscomega` which seems to do what you want.

You can define

```
\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}}
```

and use `\scOmega` in your document as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa}

\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \Omega\neq\scOmega
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you don't want to load the `tipa` package entirely, you can load `fontenc` with the option `T3` (needed for `tipa` symbols) and declare

```
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\textscomega{T3}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\textscomega{T3}

\newcommand{\scOmega}{\text{\textscomega}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \Omega\neq\scOmega
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```